# acceso a un arreglo en vue

Tags: vue.js

hola tengo una duda con relacion tengo un trozo de codigo que quiero accesar al campo "code" y es un arreglo, no se como hacerlo, este es la estructura del Json, :

```
[{estado: true,

    pasarela: [
                {
                    "code": "transbank",
                    "value": 8792
                }

]},
{estado: true,

    pasarela: [
                {
                    "code": "transbank",
                    "value": 993
                }

]}
```

quiero renderizar y mostrar el estado y el code que esta en pasarela, este es el codigo:

```
   {
                    headerName: "Estado",
                    field: "estado", 
                    width: 1100
                },
                {
                    headerName: "Codigoo",
                    field: "pasarela.code",
                 width: 750
               }
```

Por su puesto no funciona y no se como accesar, cualquier ayuda, gracias...

Comment: Que has intentado al momento?

Comment: ese es el codigo, el una lista ag grid, quiero accesar el arreglo

Comment: A lo que voy es: ¿qué has intentado programar para iterarlos?

Comment: Como es tu vue???? porque eso es lo que falta...

Comment: es solo parte que me interesa, es mostrar lo que esta en pasarela...es un ag grid